# What is DVNC and how does it work?

Tags: cryptography

As stated on [their website](http://www.thedvnc.org/):

> DVNC is not encryption but is a new branch of cryptography and
>   information science. DVNC employs a new paradigm in secret keeping to
>   keep your data secured.

I understand it is used like traditional cryptography to protect a message from being understood by an attacker, even if it is intercepted.

However, I've went through their presentation and I don't understand what it is exactly and how it works. Can someone explain to me ?

Comment: 1) Ask again on the 11th, after they release.  2) Keep your hopes low; the website has several hallmarks of snake oil or an elaborate prank.  3) I would love to see some of the local cryptography experts opine about the oft-cited (by DVNC) "coupling" in modern cryptographic algorithms - I'm no cryptographer but I'm pretty sure modern crypto by definition has been designed to break coupling. Or maybe that would be a better question for crypto.stackexchange.com...

Comment: "new" and "cryptography" are rarely terms that go well together...

Answer (score 5):

The [DVNC whitepaper](http://www.thedvnc.org/s/DVNC-Whitepaper-Publication-v05132014-rrtn.pdf) is heavy on analogies and buzzwords, light on content, and the source code is in a format I can't view, but as far as I can tell, the "key advances" of DVNC are as follows:

1. The cyphertext alphabet can be much larger than the plaintext alphabet.
2. The cyphertext alphabet can use a totally different set of symbols than the plaintext alphabet.

In short, they appear to have re-discovered some of the great advances of 17th-century cryptography.

Answer (score -1):

DVNC is about representing data without a fixed alphabet. It can be used for security by applying encryption principles, but its not new encryption.

In encryption, if you have an egg, you scramble it. Once its out of the shell, its really hard to recreate without the proper key. The scrambling process is performed by a computational transform of some sort.

In DVNC, if you have an egg, you inscribe a description of the egg onto a piece of toast. When you transmit your "egg" you don't send an egg at all, you send the toast. The receiver reads the toast and clones an egg from the instructions.

Each time you send the egg, you can use a different piece of toast. To observers, the toasts all look different even with the same egg.

Now, how is that any more secure? It isn't, its just systematic obfuscation. But like any encryption, the process can be keyed. And thats where some interesting things happen that are hyped on the website. But draw your own conclusions.

This page probably wasn't up when you last checked, and more whitepapers have since been released. It explains it in more detail.http://www.thedvnc.org/post-encryption/